# Admob Interstitial Ad showing black with new Ad unit ID

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

i have created one app and i am using admob Interstitial Ads.
As i have created new Interstitial Ad unit ID for that app but ad is showing black with close button, but if i use my old applications Ad unit ID ads will show up.
I dont know why this issue is happening?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For a newly created ad unit it may take some time before getting live ads. Add your device as a test device and check with test ads. They should render fine.

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
    .addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")  // An example device ID
    .build();
```

Comment: yes you are right. i have added test device and found code is working(ads are showing) but as app is now live on play store from last 20 hrs. still it was showing me blank ads.

Comment: probably some network issue or faulty caching. try clearing cache, deleting ad caches using some cleaning app. or reinstall. also try on other device (or second user on the same device)

Comment: also may be ur app has not sent enough requests and the ad unit id is still warming up on servers despite being live for 20 hours. just a possibility.

Comment: Unlikely to be an issue of too few requests for an interstitial. If that were the case then no ad would have been made available in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me (the cross didn't even appear) and I have the Internet permission missing in the Manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I think there are a lot of reasons why this happens.