# Android - Interstitial ads admob is displayed as black screen

Tags: android, admob, cocos2d-x

When I use an old interstitial ID, live ads is displayed right. But when I register new ID (40 hours ago) and use it, interstitial ads is displayed as black screen and cross button.

Is there any problem here?

Comment: Did you add the interstitial default activity to the manifest? Are you requesting the ad load? Did you set your ads id?

Comment: I've already set ID and request ads. The problem is that interstitial ads works correctly when using an old ID

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608474/admob-interstitial-ad-showing-black-with-new-ad-unit-id